# Why use <legend> in HTML?

Tags: html, web, logic

What's the point in using `<legend>`>?

It looks to be the same as a `<p>` tag, although it cannot be nested inside a div?

Is there a reason to use it?

Comment: The `<legend>` tag is used within the `<fieldset>` tag. This allows to create a frame around the elements it contains, and the `<legend>` tag allows to give a title to this frame. This title is displayed on the top of the frame. You want an exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A legend describes the content of a fieldset.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>What pets do you like?</legend>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="cats"> Cats </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="dogs"> Dogs </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="etc"> Etc </label>
</fieldset>
```

It has the semantic association with the form controls in that fieldset.

This allows, for example, screen readers to announce the question with each of the possible answers to provide context to what the answers are for.